# Rails 3.1 CarrierWave error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, attributes, carrierwave

I followed the tutorial http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads?view=asciicast and I've got my nested form setup with the attached inside a nested form below.  Everything works fine but the image isn't being uploaded / storing the filename in the db.

```
<%= simple_nested_form_for(@order) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="inputs">
        <label> <%= link_to 'New Customer', new_customer_path %> <small>or</small></label><div class="clear"></div>
        <%= f.association :customer, :label =>'Existing Customer', :include_blank => false %>
        <%= f.input :due_date, :as => :date, :start_year => Date.today.year, :start_day => Date.today.day, :stary_month => Date.today.month, :order => [:month, :day, :year], :input_html => { :class => 'date' }  %>
        <%= f.input :sales_tax, :input_html => { :class => 'text', :value => current_user.sales_tax, :onChange=>"itemcalculate()", :id => 'invoice-salestax' }, :hint => '%'  %>
        <%= f.input :discount, :input_html => { :class => 'text', :onChange=>"itemcalculate()", :id => 'invoice-discount' }, :placeholder => '$30', :label => 'Discount'  %>

            <%= f.fields_for :lineitems do |item| %>
                <div id='size'>
                <label style="margin-top:0 !important;">Details</label>
                <%= item.input :product_name, :input_html => { :class => 'text' }, :label => false, :wrapper_html => { :class => 'detail-wrapper' }, :input_html => { :class => 'details'}, :hint => 'Product Name', :placeholder => 'Gildan 2000'  %>
                <%= item.input :color, :input_html => { :class => 'text' }, :label => false, :wrapper_html => { :class => 'detail-wrapper' }, :input_html => { :class => 'details'}, :hint => 'Product Color', :placeholder => 'Blue'  %>
                <%= item.input :price_per, :input_html => { :class => 'text details', :onChange=>"itemcalculate()", :id => 'invoice-priceper' }, :label => false, :wrapper_html => { :class => 'detail-wrapper' }, :hint => 'Price per', :placeholder => "4.50", :required => true  %>
                <%= item.input :extra_fee, :input_html => { :class => 'text details', :onChange=>"itemcalculate()", :id => 'invoice-extrafee' }, :label => false, :wrapper_html => { :class => 'detail-wrapper', :value => '0' }, :hint => 'Extra fee', :required => true  %>
            <div class='clear'></div>
                <label>Sizes</label>                
                <%= item.input :xxs, :input_html => { :class => 'sizes', :value => '0', :onChange=>"itemcalculate()", :id => 'invoice-xxs' },  :hint=> 'xxs', :label => false, :wrapper_html => { :class => 'size-wrapper' } %>
                <%= item.input :xs, :input_html => { :class => 'sizes', :value => '0', :onChange=>"itemcalculate()", :id => 'invoice-xs' },  :hint=> 'xs', :label => false, :wrapper_html => { :class => 'size-wrapper' } %>
                <%= item.input :s, :input_html => { :class => 'sizes', :value => '0', :onChange=>"itemcalculate()", :id => 'invoice-s' },  :hint=> 's' , :label => false, :wrapper_html => { :class => 'size-wrapper' }%>
                <%= item.input :m, :input_html => { :class => 'sizes', :value => '0', :onChange=>"itemcalculate()", :id => 'invoice-m' },  :hint=> 'm', :label => false, :wrapper_html => { :class => 'size-wrapper' } %>
                <%= item.input :l, :input_html => { :class => 'sizes', :value => '0', :onChange=>"itemcalculate()", :id => 'invoice-l' },  :hint=> 'l', :label => false, :wrapper_html => { :class => 'size-wrapper' } %>
                <%= item.input :xl, :input_html => { :class => 'sizes', :value => '0', :onChange=>"itemcalculate()", :id => 'invoice-xl' },  :hint=> 'xl', :label => false, :wrapper_html => { :class => 'size-wrapper' } %>
                <%= item.input :xxl, :input_html => { :class => 'sizes', :value => '0', :onChange=>"itemcalculate()", :id => 'invoice-xxl' },  :hint=> 'xxl', :label => false, :wrapper_html => { :class => 'size-wrapper' } %>

                <label>Extra Notes</label>
                <%= item.text_area :extra_notes %>

                <!-- start image upload -->
                    <%= item.fields_for :images, :html => {:multipart => true} do |image| %>
                    <%= f.file_field :image %>
                    <%= image.link_to_remove "Remove Image", :id => 'remove-image' %>
                    <% end %>
                    <%= item.link_to_add "<img src='/images/icon-camera.png' id='camera-icon'/> Add an image".html_safe, :images, :id=> 'add-image'  %>
                <!-- end image upload -->

                <div class='clear'></div>
                <%= item.link_to_remove "Remove Item" %>

                </div>
            <% end %>

            <p id='add-new-item'><%= f.link_to_add "+ Add an Item", :lineitems  %></p>
            </div>
            <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I'm getting the error `WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: image
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: images_attributes`

My Image model looks like this:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :lineitem_id, :image
  belongs_to :lineitem, :polymorphic => true
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

end
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: images
#
#  id          :integer         not null, primary key
#  lineitem_id :integer
#  image       :string(255)
#  created_at  :datetime
#  updated_at  :datetime
#
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your image upload section, i think you want

```
<%= image.file_field :image %>
```

instead of

```
<%= f.file_field :image %>
```

sounds/looks like you're trying to tack the image file field onto the orders form when it should be part of the nested form you created for the image.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this line:

```
attr_accessible :lineitem_id, :image
```

prevents your image from saving. You should fix/improve this definition, so it accepts other parameters as well, when mass assigning.

Comment: But what other parameters could it accept?  Those are the only two fields except for id/createdby/updatedat

Comment: Imho you clearly have it written in the error message - images_attributes. If you're unsure you can always put a throw params in the create action of a controller to see what's there or log it.

Comment: I've added `images_attributes` to the Lineitem `attr_accessible` and that error is gone but still no luck with the `image` error...any suggestions?  Adding `image` as well does nothing.

Comment: I think you're missing :multipart => true definition for your form. You can refer to the docs.

Comment: Hmm, I have that in at the top http://pastie.org/3415104 and I also tried to put it inside the Image nested form but still same attribute error `WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: image`

Comment: At this point you should know what this "can't mass-assign" error means. I wonder if you have Carrierwave setup properly.

Answer (score 0):

use something like this, since im not using active record some stuff its missing.. but you should be able to adapt it to your needs..

```
class LineItem

  attr_accessible :images_attributes
  has_many :images

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, :allow_destroy => true
end

class Image
  attr_accessible :lineitem_id, :image
  belongs_to :lineitem, :polymorphic => true
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

that should work

Answer (score 0):

You need add :remove_image to attr_accessible.